# return msg.sender.balance not acting as expected

Tags: solidity, remix, metamask

I'm using MetaMask to connect to Rinkeby and I'm deploying the contracts via Remix. When I call the function returnsenderbalance it returns

```
115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039456084007913129639935
```

rather than my balance in Wei. The code is below:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.11;

contract returnbalance{
    function returnsenderbalance() constant returns (uint){
        return msg.sender.balance;  
    }
}
```

Comment: Can confirm behaviour with contract deployed [here](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x40926dce51fe43c40525e4e81b7f3413e19ab981#code)
Could not find a solidity version where it does not happen, though works as expected in the Javascript VM.  currently looking through bytecode

Comment: `function eventSenderBalance() {SenderBalance(msg.sender, msg.sender.balance); }`
logs the correct balance.

Comment: Does anyone want to chime in and describe how this was ultimately resolved? I'm thinking compiler and curious about the details.

Answer (score 1):

This is related to:

eth/api_backend.go

```
func (b *EthAPIBackend) GetEVM(ctx context.Context, msg core.Message, state *state.StateDB, header *types.Header, vmCfg vm.Config) (*vm.EVM, func() error, error) {
===> state.SetBalance(msg.From(), math.MaxBig256)
vmError := func() error { return nil }
context := core.NewEVMContext(msg, header, b.eth.BlockChain(), nil)
return vm.NewEVM(context, state, b.eth.chainConfig, vmCfg), vmError, nil
}

math.MaxBig256 == 115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039455084007913129639935
```

Is a constant in Geth( common/math/big.go)

Comment: To give more context the problem isn't in the contract, but in the go-ethereum code (the contract works as expected). The [github issue](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/16999) where it was reported. The commit where it was fixed is [here](https://github.com/holiman/go-ethereum/commit/7e33fd957a88d693b4c4603dc622dcdd5c313865). That change affected [another use case](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/21108).

Answer (score 0):

this code is working fine, try this:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

contract returnbalance{
    function returnsenderbalance() view public returns(uint){
        return msg.sender.balance;  
    }
}
```

Comment: The original contract didn't have a bug. It was a bug/feature in the geth code.