# solidity - forever can't return the msg.sender balance

Tags: solidity, cpp-ethereum, balances

this is my contract code

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.4;
contract IamHongKongTokenBack_00{ 

  // 現在我錢包的地址+Eth量
function SeeMyAddAndETHVar() public constant returns (address, uint) {
    address _myadd = msg.sender;
    return ( _myadd,  _myadd.balance);
}   

// 查看其他地址的Eth量
function SeeSheEthVar(address _InputAdd) public constant returns (address, uint) {
    address _SheAc = _InputAdd;
    return (_SheAc, _SheAc.balance);
}   


}
```

the `SeeMyAddAndETHVar` is use see my address and ETH amount

and `SeeSheEthVar` is use input address and see this address and ETH amount

If i use 0X123... address go to this contract 
now i use the SeeSheEthVar Input address 0X789...
i can see the correct address and correct ETH amount

but use SeeMyAddAndETHVar 
i will see the correct address and error ETH amount

so strange
When I change use 0X789... address go to this contract 
i will can see 0X123... correct address and correct ETH amount
but 0X789... address is both error ETH amount
[image]

May I ask where my problem is
Thanks for answer~!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT : Working use case of the msg.sender.balance on a call value. User pay gaz (thus sending a tx) to store data in the contract storage, then can call freely the last value saved for his account. It return correct balance for me even with metamask, which prove the issue I'm trying to explain you, which you need to send a tx to use the msg.sender.balance (with metamask for sure, maybe other supplier it work):

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.4;
contract IamHongKongTokenBack_00{ 


//balance stored on call of saveBalance
mapping(address => uint256)  lastBalance;

function saveBalance() public  {
    lastBalance[msg.sender] = msg.sender.balance;
}   


function fetchBalance(address _address) constant public returns (uint256) {
    return lastBalance[_address];
}   


}
```

Using msg.sender.balance and trying to return it in a constant function seems to bug.

I myself tried with remix and metamask and it's not working as it should.

But if you use in a function that cost fees (call) and let's say you store the msg.sender.balance in a event or require it over a sum, it will work because a tx object was supplied.

Check that:

[return msg.sender.balance not acting as expected](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/16781/19037)

https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/2325

https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/14989

Example of use that work for me in a "callable" function (which cost gaz to execute, modify the storage of my contract):

```
require(msg.sender.balance >= 0.01 ether);
```

This work for me, which mean if I have >= 0.01 eth in my account calling the function it execute, if not then it revert and don't execute. Which mean the "msg.sender.balance" really work as it should and contain there the correct balance of the sender.

Result of your code using metamask as web3 supplier:

```
0: address: 0xc544[...]
1: uint256: 115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457434007913129639935
```

My actual balance is 4.424 ETH so it would be supposed to return 4424000000000000000 WEI, not this random string.

Comment: (call) is need a gas?

Comment: Yup. Calling as a constant with metamask don't return the correct balance but as I said, using in a callable function and use it as a requirement or storing it in an event work.

Comment: thank you comments!! 
Maybe you could tell me a specific code?
i am sorry because i am a beginner
i don't know how to do this

Comment: Just did in my answer!

Comment: Please mark my answer as correct if I made you understand correctly the issue with msg.sender.balance, if not just ask me which part you don't understand! :)

Comment: thank you so much~
but i just can return bool
i am so sorry 
you could tell me where is my error?

Comment: Its not an error. Its that you cannot return the wallet balance using a constant function.

Comment: Did you checked the links?

Comment: i deleted the constant but it is error

Comment: You can't return the balance using metamask amd a constant, its returning not correct data. Even if you remove the constant keyword, it's not changing the function logic. You are not sending any transaction calling it, so it create a misbehavior of the msg.sender.balance with metamask. Please read about in the links I've put

Comment: Thank you

I want to look again
Is there any way to see the balance in msg.sender?

Comment: You can do it in a callable function and store in a event youll be able to see it fetching the event. As I said you can also use as a condition. Just don't forget it need to be a call where actual tx is sent. This is what I understand from what Ive read and I was having the same issue as you see.

Comment: thank you so much~
but I still can't get more specific answers
i already google the "callable" 
but i can't see the answers
anyway very thank you comment

Comment: Let me do you an example ok

Comment: just edited and put a valid code. I tested and it work as it should

Comment: Tell me if you got it :)

Comment: thank you very much again
yes it is work
although it can't like the normal wallet
but it is valuable
~!!!

Answer (score 0):

Honestly I don't understand what's the question but I tried to decrypt it and seems like you're having troubles getting the balance in case you call the function `SeeMyAddAndETHVar`. Anyway I've tried your contract on [remix](https://remix.ethereum.org/) and the behaviour is correct

```
call to IamHongKongTokenBack_00.SeeMyAddAndETHVar

{
    "0": "address: 0x14723a09acff6d2a60dcdf7aa4aff308fddc160c",
    "1": "uint256: 99999999999997000000"
}
call to IamHongKongTokenBack_00.SeeSheEthVar
{
    "0": "address: 0x14723a09acff6d2a60dcdf7aa4aff308fddc160c",
    "1": "uint256: 99999999999997000000"
}
```

Comment: thank you comments!! 

saw you comments so i test in remix VM network
this is work , can display correct ETH amount
but in private network and ethernet network it is not work

Comment: Are you using metamask as a supplier? @mirg

Comment: No you are not , I added result using metamask as a web3 supplier

Comment: The issue with this code is behavior of msg.sender.balance is not correct using metamask and a constant function, as my links show. But it can still be used in a callable function where gaz is spent and actual TX supplied.